# Random products "item****" show up in magento regularly

Tags: magento-1.9

Recently, something weird happened to my magento site.

Every a few days, hundreds and thousands random products were added. No one did that, and the weird part is that all those products are called "item***" with a specific price which is not the price from my original products. All my original products are still there, while unwanted products were added constantly.

Did anyone encounter similar problem? Any clue about where to start checking?

I am using magento 1.9

[image: admin catalog]